# First pageBlock is preventing reRender of second pageBlock. Why?

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript

Here is my code simplified so it's easy to copy and paste it in your dev console.

As the code is shown: the `middle column` will reRender, but not the `right column`. When you remove the code in the `middle column`, the `right column` code reRenders. Why will both not reRender at the same time?

VF Page

```
<apex:page controller="debugPageController">
    <apex:form >

        <script type="text/javascript">
        function doSearch() {
            console.log('doSearch is firing');

            console.log("Input value: " + document.getElementById("searchBox").value);

            searchServer(
                document.getElementById("searchBox").value
            );
        }
        </script>

        <apex:actionFunction name="searchServer" action="{!runSearch}" reRender="calendar, taskList">
            <apex:param name="searchBox" value="" />
        </apex:actionFunction>

        <input type="text" id="searchBox" value="" onkeyup="doSearch();"/>

        <!--Beginning of middle column -->
        <apex:pageBlock mode="edit" id="calendar">   


            <apex:outputPanel layout="block" styleClass="col-sm-12 col-md-8 col-lg-6">
                <apex:outputPanel layout="block" styleClass="section section-calendar">
                    <apex:outputPanel layout="block" styleClass="fc fc-unthemed fc-ltr">

                        <!-- View by Task Owner -->
                        <div class="fc-toolbar">
                            <div class="fc-left">

                                <button class="fc-next-button fc-button fc-state-default fc-corner-right">
                                    <span class="fc-icon fc-icon-right-single-arrow"></span>
                                </button>
                                <span class="arrowIcons">


                                </span>
                                <apex:commandButton value="Today"/>
                            </div>
                            <div class="fc-right">
                                <apex:commandButton value="Month"/>
                                <apex:commandButton value="Week"/>
                            </div>
                            <div class="fc-center">
                                <h2>
                                </h2>
                            </div>
                        </div>


                        <!-- Task Calendar Header End -->
                        <!-- Monthly Task Calendar -->         
                        <div class="fc-view-container">
                            <div class="fc-view fc-month-view fc-basic-view">
                                <table>
                                    <thead class="fc-head">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td class="fc-head-container fc-widget-header">
                                                <div class="fc-row fc-widget-header">
                                                    <thead>
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <th class="fc-day-header fc-widget-header fc-sun" ><span>{!searchBox}</span></th>
                                                            <th class="fc-day-header fc-widget-header fc-mon" ><span>{!searchBox}</span></th>
                                                            <th class="fc-day-header fc-widget-header fc-tue" ><span>{!searchBox}</span></th>
                                                            <th class="fc-day-header fc-widget-header fc-wed" ><span>{!searchBox}</span></th>
                                                            <th class="fc-day-header fc-widget-header fc-thu" ><span>{!searchBox}</span></th>
                                                            <th class="fc-day-header fc-widget-header fc-fri" ><span>{!searchBox}</span></th>
                                                            <th class="fc-day-header fc-widget-header fc-sat" ><span>{!searchBox}</span></th>
                                                        </tr>   
                                                    </thead> 
                                                </div>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody class="fc-body">
                                        <apex:repeat value="{!searchBox}" var="wc">
                                            {!wc}
                                        </apex:repeat>                                                            
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>

                            </div>
                        </div>  
                        <!-- Monthly Task Calendar End -->   
                    </apex:outputPanel>
                </apex:outputPanel>
            </apex:outputPanel>
        </apex:pageBlock>
        <!--End of middle column-->

        <!--Beginning of right column--> 
        <apex:pageBlock mode="edit" id="taskList">
            <apex:outputPanel layout="block" styleClass="col-sm-12 col-sm-offset-0 col-md-8 col-md-offset-4 col-lg-3 col-lg-offset-0">
                <div class="panel panel-default panel-tasks">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h3 class="panel-title">
                            Tasks
                        </h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="list-group">
                        <apex:repeat value="{!searchBox}" var="task" id="taskList">
                            <a href="/{!task}" class="list-group-item">
                                <span clas="badge"><apex:outputText value="{!task}"/></span>
                                <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">
                                    <apex:outputText value="{!task}"/>
                                    <ul class="list-unstyled">
                                        <li>
                                            <strong>Assigned To: </strong>
                                            <apex:outputText value="{!task}"/>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <strong>Related To: </strong>
                                            <apex:outputText value="{!task}"/>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </h4>
                            </a>
                        </apex:repeat>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </apex:outputPanel>
        </apex:pageBlock>

    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Controller

```
public class debugPageController {

    public String searchBox{get; set;}

    public PageReference runSearch() {
        searchBox = Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('searchBox');
        System.debug('searchBox >>>>> ' + searchBox);
        return null;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason it doesn't work is because you're generating invalid markup.

[image]

Include another `table` tag where it belongs to produce valid markup and it works just fine.

```
<div class="fc-view-container">
    <div class="fc-view fc-month-view fc-basic-view">
        <table> <!-- add another table tag -->
            <thead class="fc-head">
                <tr>
                    <td class="fc-head-container fc-widget-header">
```

Comment: why does invalid markup break the javascript?

Comment: why do web browsers even attempt to render invalid markup? Isn't this why there's a spec?